# How to generate a Link thats a google maps search result

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, search

Note: This question is NOT for problem/Issue in code. Its general question of ideas on how to?

I want the user to be able to enter an address and once he/she clicks a button I want a link to be generated that's a search result of that address on google maps. 
I have seen this somewhere it's like this-

A letter with a line

```
Location: Address and [In here a link that takes them to google maps with the search result of that Address] 
 Time:00:00
```

This letter is an appointment letter that shows them an Address where to go and the time and that address link should show them where it is on google maps.
Something like this any ideas on how to take that string/Adress in a text box that user enters and make it a google maps search result?
here is a picture of what it looks like when you click the link takes you to [Google Maps](https://www.google.ca/maps?source=tldsi&hl=en) and shows me the place like this [image: This opens up when the link is clicked] I tried looking around the internet wasn't able to find a useful info. 
Thanks for your time and kind consideration.

Comment: This looks promising:   https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Google-Maps-using-Latitude-and-Longitude-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your info but unfortunately, I don't think you understood it properly I am not trying to show them a map I want to take them to google maps original site and show them a searched result address

Comment: Let me add more info in my question

Answer (score 4):

Google has some great documentation with lots of examples at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide.

For your direct answer just replace spaces in your address with '+' and throw it in the query param.

eg. https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=toronto+street+winnipeg+mb

Of course there will be cases where your address is not understood correctly, or multiple of the same address, etc.  If you wanted something more reliable you could try using google geocoding API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Google maps API seems to do a good job of parsing an address out of the URL and locating it.  If you are in a browser you can do `https://www.google.com/maps/place/my address here` and it will take you to a map result for example:
[https://www.google.com/maps/place/1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW](https://www.google.com/maps/place/1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW).
If you want it to look more like a valid URL you can replace any spaces with a '+' https://www.google.com/maps/place/1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW

Comment: Thank You! I will try doing both method's